# Filtering query with multiple and dynamic properties in Eav Model

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-attribute-value

I have 5 tables

Advertismenet > have some ads in my application

category

category Detail > for category's properties

category Detail Definitions > for category detail definitions

Category Detail Value > for submit

i want to implement EAV model.
for example i have this sample data.

> Category
>
> - Id 1
> - Name Mobile
>
> > Category Detail
> >
> > 1. - Id 1
> >
> >      - Name Price
> >      - CategoryId 1
> >      - ControlType String
> > 2. - Id 2
> >
> >      - Name RAM
> >      - CategoryId 1
> >      - ControlType DropDown
> > 3. - Id 3
> >
> >      - Name Hard
> >      - CategoryId 1
> >      - ControlType Number

CategoryDetail Definition

1. - Id 1

     - Name 4G
     - CategoryDetailId 2
2. - Id 2

     - Name 8G
     - CategoryDetailId 2

> Advertismenet
>
> 1. - Id 1
>
>      - Name samsung galaxy
>      - CategoryId 1
> 2. - Id 2
>
>      - Name samsung galaxy
>      - CategoryId 1

Detail Value

1. - Id 1

     - AdvertisementId 1
     - DetailId 1
     - Value 530000
     - DefinitionId null
2. - Id 1

     - AdvertisementId 1
     - DetailId 2
     - Value null
     - DefinitionId 1

So i wanna have a filter page that user can select what attribute he/s wants . for example i as a user want a list of mobiles that have 8G of ram and they are Black , ....

***Update:***

```
CREATE TABLE Advertisement_Categories([Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE Advertisement_CategoryDetail_Definitions(
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Advertisement_CategoryDetailId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL)
CREATE TABLE Advertisement_CategoryDetail_Values(
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Advertisement_CategoryDetailId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[AdvertisementId] [bigint] NULL,
[Advertisement_CategoryDetail_DefinitionId] [bigint] NULL,
[Value] [nvarchar](max) NULL)
CREATE TABLE Advertisement_CategoryDetails(
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[DynamicUserControlType] [int] NOT NULL,
[Advertisement_CategoryId] [bigint] NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE Advertisements(
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Advertisement_CategoryId] [bigint] NOT NULL)

INSERT [dbo].[Advertisement_Categories] ([Id], [CreateDate], [UpdateDate], [IsArchived], [Name], [IconPath], [OrderNumber], [ParentId]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2018-12-01T07:06:50.2165209+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), CAST(N'0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), 0, N'طلا', NULL, 0, 3)
INSERT [dbo].[Advertisement_CategoryDetail_Definitions] ([Id], [CreateDate], [UpdateDate], [IsArchived], [Advertisement_CategoryDetailId], [Name], [OrderNumber], [Version]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2018-12-01T07:07:08.8619579+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), CAST(N'0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), 0, 1, N'عیار ۱۸', 0, 636792448288619526)
INSERT [dbo].[Advertisement_CategoryDetail_Definitions] ([Id], [CreateDate], [UpdateDate], [IsArchived], [Advertisement_CategoryDetailId], [Name], [OrderNumber], [Version]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2018-12-01T07:08:15.2481173+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), CAST(N'0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), 0, 2, N'سفید', 0, 636792448952481159)
INSERT [dbo].[Advertisement_CategoryDetail_Definitions] ([Id], [CreateDate], [UpdateDate], [IsArchived], [Advertisement_CategoryDetailId], [Name], [OrderNumber], [Version]) VALUES (5, CAST(N'2018-12-01T07:07:08.8619579+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), CAST(N'2018-12-01T07:07:08.8619579+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), 0, 1, N'عیار 24', 0, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Advertisement_CategoryDetail_Definitions] ([Id], [CreateDate], [UpdateDate], [IsArchived], [Advertisement_CategoryDetailId], [Name], [OrderNumber], [Version]) VALUES (6, CAST(N'2018-12-01T07:08:15.2481173+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), CAST(N'2018-12-01T07:08:15.2481173+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), 0, 2, N'زرد', 0, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Advertisement_CategoryDetail_Definitions] ([Id], [CreateDate], [UpdateDate], [IsArchived], [Advertisement_CategoryDetailId], [Name], [OrderNumber], [Version]) VALUES (7, CAST(N'2018-12-01T07:08:15.2481173+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), CAST(N'2018-12-01T07:08:15.2481173+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), 0, 2, N'سیاه', 0, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Advertisement_CategoryDetail_Values] ([Id], [CreateDate], [UpdateDate], [IsArchived], [Advertisement_CategoryDetailId], [AdvertisementId], [Advertisement_CategoryDetail_DefinitionId], [Value], [Version]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2018-12-01T07:15:22.5333139+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), CAST(N'0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), 0, 1, 11, 1, NULL, 636792453225333028)
INSERT [dbo].[Advertisement_CategoryDetail_Values] ([Id], [CreateDate], [UpdateDate], [IsArchived], [Advertisement_CategoryDetailId], [AdvertisementId], [Advertisement_CategoryDetail_DefinitionId], [Value], [Version]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2018-12-01T07:15:22.5333183+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), CAST(N'0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), 0, 2, 11, 2, NULL, 636792453225333183)
INSERT [dbo].[Advertisement_CategoryDetail_Values] ([Id], [CreateDate], [UpdateDate], [IsArchived], [Advertisement_CategoryDetailId], [AdvertisementId], [Advertisement_CategoryDetail_DefinitionId], [Value], [Version]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2018-12-01T07:15:22.5333183+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), CAST(N'2018-12-01T07:15:22.5333183+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), 0, 2, 10, 6, NULL, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[Advertisement_CategoryDetails] ([Id], [CreateDate], [UpdateDate], [IsArchived], [Name], [IsRequired], [DynamicUserControlType], [OrderNumber], [Advertisement_CategoryId], [Version]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2018-12-01T07:06:57.5101115+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), CAST(N'0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), 0, N'عیار', 0, 3, 0, 4, 636792448175100972)
INSERT [dbo].[Advertisement_CategoryDetails] ([Id], [CreateDate], [UpdateDate], [IsArchived], [Name], [IsRequired], [DynamicUserControlType], [OrderNumber], [Advertisement_CategoryId], [Version]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2018-12-01T07:08:04.5508379+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), CAST(N'0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), 0, N'رنگ', 0, 3, 1, 4, 636792448845508373)
INSERT [dbo].[Advertisements] ([Id], [CreateDate], [UpdateDate], [IsArchived], [OwnerUserId], [ProcessState], [SellKind], [Address], [Longitude], [Latitude], [Title], [Price], [DiscountPercent], [Warranty], [Description], [Advertisement_CategoryId], [ProvinceId], [CityId], [PointKind]) VALUES (10, CAST(N'2018-11-28T13:04:29.3749610+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), CAST(N'0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), 0, 1, 0, 0, N'1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA', -122.08400000000002, 37.421998333333335, N'ghfgh', CAST(65465436.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), 0, NULL, NULL, 2, 1, 1, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[Advertisements] ([Id], [CreateDate], [UpdateDate], [IsArchived], [OwnerUserId], [ProcessState], [SellKind], [Address], [Longitude], [Latitude], [Title], [Price], [DiscountPercent], [Warranty], [Description], [Advertisement_CategoryId], [ProvinceId], [CityId], [PointKind]) VALUES (11, CAST(N'2018-12-01T07:15:20.4668455+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), CAST(N'0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00' AS DateTimeOffset), 0, 1, 0, 0, N'1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA', -122.08400000000002, 37.421998333333335, N'dfgsfdg', CAST(225000000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), 0, NULL, NULL, 4, 1, 1, 2)
```

How can i select a list of advertisements with multiple filter 
remember that every attribute is on one row so i cant use just 'and'

Comment: A `WHERE` can have multiple clauses, not just one. `WHERE Column1 = 'A' and Column2 = 2` is perfectly valid; you're not limited to 1 clause.

Comment: I can't really figure out this data model.  Having data in a tabular format would really help.

Comment: @Larnu i cant do that cause nothing would match that becuase every row has just one property not all properties

Comment: That's not the visualisation I got from your description. @GordonLinoff is right, we need tabular format data here; or even better DDL (`CREATE`) and DML (`INSERT`) statements.

Comment: ive just added some scripts to go with @Larnu

Comment: some scripts added for you @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0):

This query could be helpful

```
select * from Advertisements where 
exists (select AdvertisementId from Advertisement_CategoryDetail_Values where  AdvertisementId = Advertisements.id  and  Advertisement_CategoryDetailId = 1 and Advertisement_CategoryDetail_DefinitionId = 1)
and
exists (select AdvertisementId from Advertisement_CategoryDetail_Values where AdvertisementId = Advertisements.id  and Advertisement_CategoryDetailId = 2 and Advertisement_CategoryDetail_DefinitionId = 2)
```